# result set doesn't close correctly

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement, resultset

I need to do some operation and I have this code:

```java
ResultSet rsSel = null;
// preparated statemen
PreparedStatement stmtSel = null;
// preparated statemen
PreparedStatement stmtUpd = null;
try {
  //create query yyyyyyyy
  String query = SQLStatements.getStatement("queryExample");

  //create PreparedStatement
  stmtSel = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(query);

  int index = 1;
  // WHERE:
  stmtSel.setInt(index++, prog);
                                    
  // SELECT:
  rsSel = stmtSel.executeQuery(); //the problem is here
  rsSel.next();  
  //close finally          
  rsSel.close()
```

and in my finally I do:

```
finally{
  close(stmtSel);
close(rsSel);
}
```

I don't know why when the programs does `rsSel = stmtSel.executeQuery();` it gives me :

```
Closing a result set you left open! Please close it yourself.: java.lang.Throwable: STACKTRACE
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: You could try swapping the order of the statements in  `finally` to close the result set before the statement.

Comment: General good practice: use try with resource whenever you can. Statements and results can be automatically closed that way.

Comment: I agree with QuentinC, don't use these kinds of outdated close utilities. The problem here is that you close them in the wrong order (you close the statement before the result set, while you should close the result set before the statement). If you had used [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), this would have been avoided.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by too wide scopes, a hidden exception maybe or some quirk in the control flow. Best is to use try-with-resources which also closes on return/break/exception. Then you would have:

```
String query = SQLStatements.getStatement("queryExample");
try (PreparedStatement stmtSel = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
    int index = 1;
    stmtSel.setInt(index++, prog);
    ...
    try (ResultSet rsSel = stmtSel.executeQuery()) {
        if (rsSel.next()) {
            ...
        }
    } // Closes rsSel
} // Closes stmtSel
```

The cast to PreparedStatement is not needed, assuming you import the `java.sql.PreparedStatement`.

---

By the way:

Indentation in java was with the introduction as per convention set to 4.
One wanted "less deep nesting of statements." An indentation of 2 I now have in a Delphi Pascal project. Conventions in java are well upheld.

Answer (score 0):

Close rssel first and then stmtsel

```
try{
   ......
} finally{
   close(rsSel);
   close(stmtSel);
}
```